# Pagebreaks in column 'groups' for SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm working on an SSRS matrix that draws information from an SQL database. Right now, the report works just fine on a small scale, but depending on parameters a report could return thousands of columns. I'd like to set up the matrix to split data into pages, with a maximum of 100 columns per page, both for ease of reading and performance.

I know how to do this with row groups in SSRS (=ceiling(rownumber(nothing)/100), but I can not find an equivalent for columns. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to create page breaks on columns. However, there are some ways you could work around this. If you're concerned about printing, you could adjust the page size both in the report and in whichever program you export to. Besides that, I'm not sure why you would want to break it up in the first place.

Another option would be to create a calculated field similar to the row number that segments the data into groups of 100 columns in the SQL and then use a row page break on that. So you would have the first 100 columns on one page and the next 100 on the next page and so on. However, if a row has attributes in many of those columns, the output may be difficult to interpret as the data for each row is broken out onto multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The main reason I want to break up the pages is performance, on my other reports, where I could page the rows, I noticed a sharp increase in performance at larger scales (1000+ rows). In *most* cases of this report colum numbers will be small, but there are instances where many thousands columns could be returned, so a cleaner way to move through the data than the built in scroll bar would be good.

Comment: As to the calculated field, I'll look into that, my other searching has also recommended plopping the whole matrix into a list structure and paging that. We shall see, I'll post here if I find a solution.